# Carousel Page navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms

i just want to ask about carousel page flow direction. I know that Carousel View has the option of flow direction, but i cant seem to find that carousel page would have the same. 
So I am trying to come up with something that would solve my issue. 
I have a main page with 2 buttons one of them takes me to Carousel 1 and with swipe to the right side i get carousel 2 and the other to carousel two with swipe to the right to carousel 1. however i am requested to changed the flow so if i go to carousel 2 i  swipe left to get carousel 1.

```
I have tried switch case but for some reason the first page doesnt load properly


     //    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                //    //model.Busy = false;
                //    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                //    {
                //        switch (_pages)
                //        {
                //            case Pages.Reading:
                //                await Navigation.PushAsync(new CarouselLearning(false), false);
                //                break;
                //            case Pages.Listening:
                //                await Navigation.PushAsync(new CarouselLearning(true), false);
                //                break;

                //        }
                //        Navigation.RemovePage(this);
                //    });
                //});

and then i tried just simple navigation which of course dosent work
 private async void OnListeningButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new CarouselLearning(Listening));
        }
```

Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: CarouselPage has been deprecated in favor of CaouselView, so why don't you use CarouselView if it has the feature you need?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/

Answer (score 0):

In [Carousel Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page), you choose to go to Carousel 1 or Carousel 2 by setting `CurrentPage`, for example:

```
public MainPageCS(bool isReading) {

    var greenContentPage = new ContentPage
    {
        Padding = padding,
        Content = new StackLayout {
        ...
    }
    };
    var blueContentPage = new ContentPage
    {
        Padding = padding,
        Content = new StackLayout {
        ...
    }
    };

    Children.Add(blueContentPage );
    Children.Add(greenContentPage);

    if (isReading)
    {
        this.CurrentPage = greenContentPage;
    }
    else
    {
        this.CurrentPage = blueContentPage ;
    }
}
```

If you go to Carousel 1, then swipe right to go to Carousel 2, if you go to Carousel 2, then swipe left to go to Carousel 1.

BTW, you can also use [CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/populate-data) to achieve what you want.

Set the [CurrentItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/interaction) to Carousel 1 or Carousel 2 when you navigate to the `CarouselLearning` Page.

Or use `FlowDirection` of CarouselView to